# Uniform convergence of a sequence of functions with a logarithm

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I calculated that the sequence of functions $f_n:(0, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f_n(x)=nx^2\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{nx}\right)$ converges pointwise to $f(x)=x$, but I have no clue about how to find $\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|$. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Hint: study the function $f_n-f$. Look at its derivative.

Comment: I've done it but I don't get what you mean

Comment: I've posted an answer, let me know if it is not what you were really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to study the uniform convergence of $(f_n)_n$ towards $f$ on $(0,+\infty)$. You said you wanted to determine $\Vert f_n -f \Vert_{\infty} := \sup |f_n(x)-f(x)|$, therefore I suggested to look at $f_n'-f'$, esp. its sign in order to have information on possible extrema of $f_n-f$ and find explicitly $\Vert f_n -f \Vert_{\infty}$, as it is the common method. But in most cases, you don't have to find this value explicitly (it can be tough), you just need to show that there exists a sequence $(M_n)_n$ such that,
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \forall x \in (0,\infty), |f_n(x) -f(x)| \leq M_n \text{ and } \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} M_n = 0$$
The most important thing is to make sure that $M_n$ is independant of $x$.

Therefore, I will suggest an answer that will establish the uniform convergence with the latter method.

---

**Preliminary result :**

$$\forall x \geq 0, \quad x \geq \ln(1+x)\geq x-\frac{x^2}{2} \quad (\ast)$$
This is a classic inequality, which is not too hard to establish (try do to it yourself if you are not already familiar with it).

---

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x>0$, therefore applying $(\ast)$ with $\frac{1}{nx}$ yields,
$$\frac{1}{nx} \geq \ln \left(1+\dfrac{1}{nx} \right) \geq \dfrac{1}{nx}-\dfrac{1}{2n^2 x^2} $$
Hence, multiplying both sides by $nx^2>0$, we get,
$$x \geq nx^2\ln\left(1 + \dfrac{1}{nx}\right) \geq x - \dfrac{1}{2n}$$
substracting $x$ to both sides finally gives us,
$$0 \geq f_n(x)-f(x) \geq -\dfrac{1}{2n}$$
hence, as it holds for any $x>0$, we get
$$ \forall x>0, |f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \dfrac{1}{2n}$$
Therefore,
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \Vert f_n-f \Vert_{\infty} = 0 $$
which proves the desired result.